# NHibernate Cascading SaveUpdate

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, sessionfactory

I'm having problems with saving associations by cascading saveupdate on my entities. I have this mapping override and would like to save it's one-to-many association by cascading, but this doesn't work.

```
public class DomainMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Tcf.Domain.Entities.Domain>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the specified mapping.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mapping">The mapping.</param>
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Tcf.Domain.Entities.Domain> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("domeinen");
        mapping.Map(m => m.Code, "code_1");
        mapping.Map(m => m.Description, "omschrijving");
        mapping.Map(m => m.Explanation, "toelichting");
        mapping.Map(m => m.CreatedBy, "createdby");
        mapping.Map(m => m.ModifiedBy, "modifiedby");
        mapping.Map(m => m.DateCreated, "createdat");
        mapping.Map(m => m.DateModified, "modifiedat");
        mapping.HasMany<SubDomain>(m => m.SubDomains).KeyColumn("domein").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

The object itself is saved, but not the association, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this error message occurs when you try to start a transaction on a session that already has an open transaction. I would need to know more about your session wrapper to give a better answer.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will edit my post and copy the wrapper code.

Comment: Which ForEach is it breaking on? I have to say that your approach seems very overcomplicated to me. Can't you accomplish the same thing using cascading?

Comment: Can you explain to me how this cascading works? Do you have an example?

Comment: I found the cascading option and it works great! I'm just getting started with NHibernate and i already thought it was a pain to save associations, but now it's easy :-). I'm going to try it on the server and see if it works now...

Comment: It works on the server, but he does not save the associations.

Answer (score 0):

The problems was inside my AutoPersistenceModel generation. My foreign key convention didn't match up.

It was mapping to DomainId, but the column name insinde SQL server is domein.